# Проблемы с передачей данных через сокеты

Tags: java, android, сокет

Решил изучить сетевое программирование на Java, и начал с сокетов. Для старта решил создать Android чат-клиент, в котором можно переписываться в реальном времени, данные передаются через сокеты. Чтобы понять принцип, сначала просто переписал код простейшего соединения клиента с сервером. Однако при попытке соединения с сервером (Android устройство - клиент, компьютер - сервер) возникает исключение ClassNotFoundException:

```
I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```

Разрешение на подключение к Интернету в манифесте оформил, подключение создаю в отдельном потоке.

Код клиента:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("26.242.96.221");
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 8080);

    System.out.println("socket = " + socket);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            out.println("howdy " + i);
            String str = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        out.println("END");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Код сервера:

```
public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Started: " + s);
        try {
            Socket socket = s.accept();
            try {
                System.out.println("Connection accepted: " + socket);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                while (true) {
                    String str = in.readLine();
                    if (str.equals("END"))
                        break;
                    System.out.println("Echoing: " + str);
                    out.println(str);
                }
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("closing...");
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Я нашёл вот такой ответ:

> Mediatek исправил эти библиотеки для добавления контроля HTTP-запросов. Он пытается динамически загрузить некоторые методы, определенные в /system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar, но, вероятно, он отсутствует или недоступен в файловой системе вашего устройства Android.

Неужели в моём устройстве из-за этого не получится работать с сокетами? Если нет, то каким ещё образом можно передавать данные между устройствами (текст, музыка, онлайн трансляции)? Буду благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось до ужаса просто: дело в том, что я подключался к серверу (компьютеру), у которого доступ в Интернет совершался через Wi-Fi, используя на своём Android-устройстве мобильную сеть, ничего не происходило. Но когда я и телефон подключил к Wi-Fi сети, то всё заработало. Как я понял это

```
I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```

не ошибка, а предупреждение связанное с тем, что Mediatek на Android пытается найти класс, но его нет в файловой системе устройства. И это на работу не влияет. Осталось понять, как подключаться к компьютеру через любое подключение